# how to delay process

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I am retrying api call if I get 401 response but before completing my retrying process my api call is executing I want to run retry process then only I want to call api following is my api where I am retrying process

```
Future<void> postvehickes(BuildContext context, String vehicleType) async {
    //print(token);

    var data = {"vehicletype": vehicleType, "filename": vehicleType};
    Map<String, String> obj = {"attributes": json.encode(data).toString()};

    var flutterFunctions =
        Provider.of<FlutterFunctions>(context, listen: false);
    final url = Ninecabsapi().urlHost + Ninecabsapi().getvehicle;
    try {
      final client = await RetryClient(
        http.Client(),
        retries: 1,
        when: (response) {
          return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
        },
        onRetry: (req, res, retryCount)  {
          //print('retry started $token');
          if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
             Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                .restoreAccessToken();

            req.headers['Authorization'] = token!;
            print('retry started ${req.headers['Authorization']}');
            //req.headers.clear();

          }
        },
      );
      loading();
      var response = await http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url))
        ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
            "imagefile", flutterFunctions.imageFile!.path,
            contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg")))
        //..headers['Authorization'] = token!
        ..fields.addAll(obj);

      final send = await client.send(response);
      final res = await http.Response.fromStream(send);
      var messages = json.decode(res.body);
      loading();

      print("this is from postvehicles $messages");
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

following is my api where I am restoring access token if expires I want to complete the whole process  before executing above api

```
Future<void> restoreAccessToken() async {
    print('restoreAccessToken started');
    final url = '${Ninecabsapi().urlHost}${Ninecabsapi().login}/$sessionId';

    var response = await http.patch(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': accessToken!
      },
      body: json.encode(
        {"refresh_token": refreshtoken},
      ),
    );
    var userDetails = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      print(userDetails['messages']);
    }

    print(userDetails);
    sessionId = userDetails['data']['session_id'];
    accessToken = userDetails['data']['access_token'];
    accessTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['access_token_expiry']),
    );
    refreshToken = userDetails['data']['refresh_token'];
    refreshTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['refresh_token_expiry']),
    );

    //print(userDetails);

    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final userData = json.encode({
      'sessionId': sessionId,
      'refreshToken': refreshToken,
      'refreshExpiry': refreshTokenExpiryDate!.toIso8601String(),
      'accessToken': accessToken,
      'accessTokenExpiry': accessTokenExpiryDate!.toIso8601String()
    });

    prefs.setString('userData', userData);
    reset();
  }
```

here I had tried async and await to my retry client and I had awaited the restoreAccessToken but the process is not waiting before I implement headers
[image: here you can see 2 markings in image]in this image I want white marking response to be top on red marking response

Answer (score 0):

Try removing await from this

```
final client = await RetryClient(
        http.Client(),
        retries: 1,
        when: (response) {
          return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
        },
        onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) async {
          //print('retry started $token');
          if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
            await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                .restoreAccessToken();

            req.headers['Authorization'] = token!;
            print('retry started ${req.headers['Authorization']}');
            //req.headers.clear();

          }
        },
      );
```

change the above code to

```
final client = RetryClient(
        http.Client(),
        retries: 1,
        when: (response) {
          return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
        },
        onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) async {
          //print('retry started $token');
          if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
            await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                .restoreAccessToken();

            req.headers['Authorization'] = token!;
            print('retry started ${req.headers['Authorization']}');
            //req.headers.clear();

          }
        },
      );
```

Comment: both are the same you had use if condition I had used ternary expression

Comment: No in your case it will return false if statuscode is 401 and in the answer it will return null.. by the way just asking are you sure that you should return true if its 401? Shouldnt it be false if statuscode is 401? Whats retry client?

Comment: [link][https://pub.dev/packages/http] you can look into retrying request here which will retry request upon 401 response

Comment: Says invalid page

Comment: it is http package in pub.dev

Comment: it dint work I had tried by removing await again post vehicles running before completion of restoreAccessToken

Comment: Are you awaiting restore access token method when it's called?

Comment: ya you can go through my code in question I am awaiting  access token method

Comment: I believe that it shows the output when it fails too. I suggest you to extract that method and then return the value after all the retries are done.

Comment: yeah I am trying to extract that method before returning value but my value is returning first

Comment: I am not Abel to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247691/discussion-between-santosh-kumar-and-kaushik-chandru).